# Combining Tables With Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

| ITEM | SPEC |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1-1 |
| B | B1-1 |
| AZ | A1-1 |
| BZ | B1-1 |

| ITEM | STOCK |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| AZ | 3 |
| BZ | 4 |

And I want to combine both tables into one:

| ITEM | SPEC | STOCK1 | STOCK2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1-1 | 1 | 3 |
| B | B1-1 | 2 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

With sample data you posted (as images)

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (item, spec) as
  3    (select 'A', 'A1-1' from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 'B1-1' from dual union all
  5     select 'C', 'C1-1' from dual union all
  6     select 'AZ','A1-1' from dual union all
  7     select 'BZ','B1-1' from dual union all
  8     select 'CZ','C1-1' from dual
  9    ),
 10  t2 (item, stock) as
 11    (select 'A', 1 from dual union all
 12     select 'B', 2 from dual union all
 13     select 'C', 5 from dual union all
 14     select 'AZ',3 from dual union all
 15     select 'BZ',4 from dual union all
 16     select 'CZ',6 from dual
 17    )
```

one option - that produces desired result - is to *double*-join the 2nd table with the 1st one on `item` column: once to fetch MIN stock value, and another time to fetch MAX stock value:

```
 18  select
 19    min(a.item) item,
 20    a.spec,
 21    min(b.stock) stock1,
 22    max(c.stock) stock2
 23  from t1 a join t2 b on a.item = b.item
 24            join t2 c on a.item = c.item
 25  group by a.spec
 26  order by a.spec;

IT SPEC     STOCK1     STOCK2
-- ---- ---------- ----------
A  A1-1          1          3
B  B1-1          2          4
C  C1-1          5          6

SQL>
```

Comment: Wonderful how you guessed the specification that wasn't actually given in plain English.

Comment: Ha! @Bogdan, the fact that this query produces desired result doesn't actually mean that I guessed specification right as there was NO specification :)